# Sending messages to multiple rooms using Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, channel

Is it possible to send messages to multiple rooms using socket.io?

Sending to 1 room:

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit("id", {})
```

Sending to N rooms:

```
io.sockets.in(room1, room2, roomN).emit("id", {})
```

Comment: it seems `sockets.in(r1).in(r2)` does not work in 0.9.16 ;(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **sockets.in** method only accepts one room as an argument, so to broadcast to multiple rooms you would have to reset the room, in between emissions. Something like this should work:

```
['room1', 'room2', 'room3'].forEach(function(room){
    io.sockets.in(room).emit("id", {});
});
```

Comment: Updated the answer for 0.9.16

Comment: Unfortunately so. I suppose if you wanted to, you could always modify the sockets object, and add a multi-room method.

Comment: Looking at the source it does not seem like a quick fix would be enough, I will stick with emitting to two rooms separately ;)

Comment: I see that you use `io.sockets.in(room).emit` and not `io.to(room).emit` does it different in any matter?

Comment: @RazBuchnik It is the same

Comment: That answer is outdated as for socket.io v4 it is possible to emit one message to multiple rooms by providing an array

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's possible to emit to multiple rooms altogether. From [the tests](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/b3fc530abefd384b3a89ff5493e97f3ef85098d4/test/socket.io.js#L1873-L1876):

```
socket.on('emit', function(room){
  sio.in('woot').in('test').emit('a');
  sio.in('third').emit('b');
});
```

That's because when you use `to` or `in` you're appending the room to the list of rooms to be targeted. From the [source code (lib/socket.js)](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/b3fc530abefd384b3a89ff5493e97f3ef85098d4/lib/socket.js#L176-L181):

```
Socket.prototype.to =
Socket.prototype.in = function(name){
  this._rooms = this._rooms || [];
  if (!~this._rooms.indexOf(name)) this._rooms.push(name);
  return this;
};
```

Comment: This is the right answer (I don't know if the other one was ever correct).

Answer (score 6):

Updated as of Socket.IO v2.0.3

```
// sending to all clients in 'game1' and/or in 'game2' room, except sender
socket.to('game1').to('game2').emit('nice game', "let's play a game (too)");
```

https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**

As of Socket.IO v4.0.0, emission to multiple rooms is now possible. Per the docs, this is how it should be done with the modified `to()` method:

```
io.to(["room1", "room2", "room3"]).emit(/* ... */);

socket.to(["room1", "room2", "room3"]).emit(/* ... */);
```

Link to the docs themselves: https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-4-release/