# Socket Emit To Specific Rooms

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I am using NodeJS, ExpressJS & Socket.IO. Now for one to one user chat room. I can simply subscribe both of them to a specific chat room and update messages via Socket.IO.
But I am stuck in a situation where let us say that I have the following chat rooms.

```
const rooms = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
```

And I only want to broadcast a certain message to room `4, 7, 8, 10` How can I do that from server side.

Generally when I have to send a message in just a single room I do the following

```
const roomid = 4;
global.io.sockets.in(roomid).emit('new message', {  message: newPost });
```

But for this use case I have multiple rooms, and i want to emit to specific rooms a single message at the same time if their socket connection is up (means the user is online).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304236/sending-messages-to-multiple-rooms-using-socket-io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a table with the rooms you want to send your message to. Loop in that table and check if room has connections, if true, send message.

Example:

```
const roomsToEmit = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3'];
const message = 'some message';

roomsToEmit.forEach((roomID) => {
    if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomID].length > 0) {
        io.sockets.in(roomID).emit('new message', {  message });
    }
});
```

If you want to do it asynchronously, but I might not be more efficient (I think socket.io handles this as you don't have to wait for anything when emitting to a WS).

```
const roomsToEmit = ['room1', 'room2', 'room3'];
const message = 'some message';

Promise.all(roomsToEmit.map((room) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomID].length > 0) {
              io.sockets.in(roomID).emit('new message', {  message });
         } 
         return resolve(roomID);
    });
})
.then((result) => {
    // all messages emited
    // console.log(result) // array of the rooms where a message was emited
});
```

Comment: Is there any other approach where I don't have to use a for loop or any loop for that purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know. Even if socket.io a did provide a way like `io.sockets.in([1,2,3]).emit('new message', {  message });` it would do a loop under the hood

Comment: I am looking for a method where I can optimally do this. Should I do it with a loop, a queue based system. What's the best approach here?

Comment: I believe a loop is fine, you can just wrap it in function. I've updated my answer to give a way to do it asynchronously, but I'm not sure it's more efficient, maybe it is when you are looping through a lot of rooms. You would have to benchmark it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think this will do for now. I will probably have to do something to benchmark it though :)

Answer (score 0):

`socket.to('room name').emit('eventname',data)` will send the data to all user present in the room except the sender , `io.to('room name').emit('eventname',data)` will send the data to all users including sender . you can check https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/ for further details.
you just need to do `io.to('1').emit('newMssage',{  message: newPost })`

Comment: I want a way where I can send data to multiple rooms at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example

```
io.to("room1").to("room2").to("room3").emit("some event");
```

you can have detailed information on
https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/